# Props is undefined when exporting with redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using redux-form to store the state of my form:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import formFields from './formFields';
import OrderField from './OrderField';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
class OrderForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.renderFields = this.renderFields.bind(this);
    }


    renderFields() {
        return _.map(formFields, ({ label, name }) => {
            return (
                    <Field
                key={name}
                component={OrderField}
                type="text"
                label={label}
                name={name}
                    />
            );
        });
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.props.onOrderSubmit)}>
            {this.renderFields()}
            <button type="/submitOrder" className="teal btn-flat right white-text">
            Next
            <i className="material-icons right">done</i>
            </button>
            </form>
                </div>
        );
    }

}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'orderForm'
})(OrderForm);
```

Container form:

```
import OrderForm from './OrderForm';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
class OrderNew extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.submitOrder = this.submitOrder.bind(this);
    }

    submitOrder(values) {
        if (this.props.total === 0) {
            console.log("cart is empty");
            //this.props.submitOrder(values);
        } else {
            console.log("handle submit order");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <OrderForm
            onOrderSubmit={ this.submitOrder }/>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'orderForm'
})(OrderNew);
```

But I'm getting the error that:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `ConnectedField`.

(Note that the `handleSubmit` prop comes from [redux-form itself](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/faq/handlevson.md/).)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: handleSubmit is supposed to be built in from redux-form

Comment: The problem seems to be with your ```OrderField``` component that you import in the file where you declare ```OrderForm```. What does this component render and/or is the path to this component correct, i.e. check it is not undefined?